# Creating a vector of maximum values from nloop in R

Tags: r

Here is r code:

```
nloop=100
xmax=list()
for(iloop in nloop){y=rtriangle(10, 0, 2, 1)
xmax[iloop]=max(y)}
```

xmax returns a list of 99 NULL values and 1 max value. How can I get this list to display all 100 max values.

Comment: Where did `rtriangle` come from?

Comment: @RichardScriven maybe http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/triangle/index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know where your `rtriangle` function comes from, but you have an error in declaring your loop. It should be `for (iloop in 1:nloop)`. In this way the `iloop` object will assume one after another all the elements of the `1:nloop` vector. As per your code, `iloop` could assume only the `nloop` value (100): this is the reason why you have 99 NULL elements of your list.

Comment: Another way would be to do `for (iloop in seq_len(nloop))`.